# Write a simple search module in ASP.NET to be called by AJAX; facing architectural dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got an existing site in ASP.NET with an embedded synchronous search function that I'd like to break out into a module I can call asychronously using AJAX. The host is Azure and the database is SQL Server.

The search function is currently written in an MVC3/EF application and called synchronously from within an ASCX page where its JSON output is rendered into HTML. The EF is demonstrably inefficient and I need to at the very least refactor that (using light ORM and handwritten procs) and update the controller. However, In looking at the requirement, I wonder if MVC is my only option and have found three other potential ones I listed below in the diagram.

I'd like to know what options I have with ASP.NET to rewrite and isolate the search function below. The simplest approach (for me) is to use a Web Forms app type with an .ASCX file composed of nothing but a `[WebMethod]` decorated function that calls a data access class (or Dapper ORM class) to return LINQ data to transform to JSON to output to the caller (an AJAX JavaScript method).

However, I have heard of WebAPI and have also thought about MVC again, using, of course, the lighter ORM as the model so I can customize the data access.

What would the tradeoffs be in terms of the three approaches I've described below in the spec diagram I created? Are there considerations I'm missing in my first-round of analysis?

[image: Architecture and Constraints]

Comment: I believe you should use your current approach for JSON methods - overall you won't likely to see any significant difference.

Comment: In terms of keeping the MVC3 controller and replacing my EF with the more efficient data access?

Comment: in terms of selecting between using your web framework - WebForms, WebApi, Mvc. Also did you check which part of EF query is inefficient? Sometimes using projections make things look much better.

Comment: I ran dotTrace against the working app in production, and the model methods that handled the dynamic search predicates were crawling and the SQL was fairly generic and not optimized.

Comment: IMHO, if you're rewriting the whole thing, might as well update to MVC/Web API (they can live together, or not, your call). You can _isolate_ with Web API (alone) if you want as well (called by your existing  app via XHR, etc.). I wouldn't think how you improve your data access should affect the "web framework" decision (EF or "old school" ADO)....

Comment: Often if you can write manually query in SQL, it's possible to create a very close query in Entity Framework, so it's  still possible you don't need to rewrite everything.